# Scaling before multi-variate multi-output regression

Tags: python, data-science

What happens if you apply scaling to your data before doing linear regression?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

scaling required: to make gradient descent coverage more quickly (means make number of iteration or cycle less to reach local minima). to make gradient descent fast you need to make multiple features value on same range scale. like -1 < x < 1. not one value is 5 , other value is 0.1 .. and so on

why we need to do this : let's imagine you have two features x1 and x2. x1 value size in large is more compare to x2 , in that case your cost function will come in a very skewed elliptical shape. this means training will be longer to reach local minima.

for more clarity please follow this link : https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/xx3Da/gradient-descent-in-practice-i-feature-scaling